# Error appending String to Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, struct

I have this struct:

```
public struct GIReservation{
    var name: String!
    var mobile: String! 
    var datetime: String!
    var people: Int!
    var info: String?
    var id: String?
}
```

And another class which implements:

```
public class GIReservationCalendarViewModel {

    public func newReservation(reservation: GIReservation) {
        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.requestSerializer.setValue(Authenticator.getAccessToken(), forHTTPHeaderField: API_HEADER_ACCESSTOKEN)
        var parameters = ["name": reservation.name, "mobile": reservation.mobile, "datetime" : reservation.datetime, "people" : reservation.people]

        if let safeInfo = reservation.info {
            parameters["info"] = safeInfo
        }
        manager.POST(self.reservationsURL, parameters: parameters, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            println("saved!")
        }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            println("OPS!")
        }

    }
}
```

But on this line:

```
parameters["info"] = safeInfo
```

And from that I get this error

> cannot assign to the result of this expression

But... why!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parameters` is inferred as `NSDictionary` because you are using mixed types like `String!` and `Int!`.

```
public struct GIReservation{
    var name: String!
    var mobile: String! 
    var datetime: String!
    var people: Int!
    var info: String?
    var id: String?
}

// Here an immutable NSDictionary is inferred as type by the compiler
// because you are mixing reservation.people witch is an Int! with
// other String! types
var parameters = ["name": reservation.name, "mobile": reservation.mobile, "datetime" : reservation.datetime, "people" : reservation.people]

if let safeInfo = reservation.info {
    parameters["info"] = safeInfo
}
```

But you can not add anything to a `NSDictionary`, it's immutable. Therefore the error "cannot assign to the result of this expression". You will need either `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
var parameters: NSMutableDictionary = ["name": reservation.name, "mobile": reservation.mobile, "datetime" : reservation.datetime, "people" : reservation.people]

if let safeInfo = reservation.info {
    parameters["info"] = safeInfo
}
```

Or Swift: `[String:AnyObject]`

```
var parameters: [String:AnyObject] = ["name": reservation.name, "mobile": reservation.mobile, "datetime" : reservation.datetime, "people" : reservation.people]

if let safeInfo = reservation.info {
    parameters["info"] = safeInfo
}
```

Comment: Oh, so, when I want to have a mutable Swift Dictionary, I should type it? Ok, thanks!

Comment: Usually var is enough instead of let, but the Obj-C Bridge behaves different.